# Vitest does not find file of dependency

Tags: vitest

I have dependency that vite easily can utilize but when runnin vitest the same dependency creates issues in the sense that its index.js file references a ./src/chartAt module that does exist as ./src/chartAt.js but some how vitest cannot find it and throws an error with

```
[error] Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\tom\frontend\node_modules\multibyte\dist\esm\src\charAt' imported from C:\Users\tom\frontend\node_modules\multibyte\dist\esm\index.js
```

My vitest.config.ts is

```
export default defineConfig({
   test: {
      environment: 'jsdom',
      threads: false,
      coverage: {
         provider: 'c8',
         reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html', 'lcov'],
         reportsDirectory: path.join(__dirname, 'analysis/coverage')
      }
   },

   resolve: {
      alias: ResolveAliases
   }
});
```

and I use the same aliases in my vite.config.

Ideas?
Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another package (`@hexlabs/dynamo-ts`). It seems not to be an issue from `vitest` but from the package that do not handle correcly ESM.

If you can't do anything to fix the package, there is a workaround with vitest. Add this to your `vite.config.ts` / `vitest.config.ts` by replacing `<your_package_name>` with the name of the package that give you trouble:

```
// ...

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  test: {
    // ...
    deps: {
      optimizer: {
        ssr: {
          enabled: true,
          include: ["<your_package_name>"],
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my GH issue on vitest: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/5309